# Paypal integration in asp.net mvc 5. How to get buyer data after the payment was processed?

Tags: asp.net, paypal

Trying to get data after the payment was successfully made from PayPal to confirm the transaction and to include this in my database

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

To get it back this is what I have done so far:

public string GetPaypalRespons(string tx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The tx is {0}", tx);
            try 
            {
                authToken = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Token"];

```
             txToken = tx;

            string query = string.Format("cmd =_notify-synch&tx={0}&at={1}",txToken,authToken);

            string url = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["test_url"];

            HttpWebRequest reqs =  (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);

            reqs.Method = "POST";

            reqs.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

            reqs.ContentLength = query.Length;

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            StreamWriter outStrmWriter = new StreamWriter(reqs.GetRequestStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

            outStrmWriter.Write(query);

            outStrmWriter.Close();

            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(reqs.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());

            strReponse = reader.ReadToEnd();

            reader.Close();

            if (strReponse.StartsWith("SUCCESS"))
            {
                return strReponse;
            }
            else
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
        }
```